# Taiwanese traveling to Europe via Istanbul, do I need a transit visa or e-visa?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, istanbul, taiwanese-citizens

I am a Taiwanese passport holder , will travel to Europe transit in Istanbul for 2 hours (inside airport only) , do I need to apply for a transit visa or an e-visa?

Comment: You need [eVisa](https://www.passportindex.org/comparebyPassport.php?p1=tw&fl=&s=yes) to Turkey